I'm encountering an issue with my Xcode build pipeline for VisionOS app in Azure Pipelines
I'm encountering an issue with my Xcode build pipeline in Azure Pipelines. When attempting to build my Xcode project using the Xcode task, I'm receiving the following error:

xcodebuild: error: Found no destinations for the scheme 'GridControl' and action build.

Here below is my Pipelines config
trigger:
- vos-pipeline

pool:
  vmImage: 'macos-13'

steps:
- script: |
    sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode_15.2.app
  displayName: 'Select Xcode 15.2'

- task: Xcode@5
  inputs:
    actions: 'build'
    sdk: 'xros'
    configuration: 'Release'
    xcWorkspacePath: '**/*.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace'
    xcodeVersion: 'default' # Options: 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, default, specifyPath

Full Error

/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk xros -configuration Release -workspace /Users/runner/work/1/s/GridControl.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace -scheme GridControl build CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=NO | /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin/xcpretty -r junit --no-color
2024-04-02 11:07:01.119 xcodebuild[1384:8170] Writing error result bundle to /var/folders/0x/nsz8g_tn7cn5l93m_zpy54xr0000gn/T/ResultBundle_2024-02-04_11-07-0001.xcresult
xcodebuild: error: Found no destinations for the scheme 'GridControl' and action build.
##[error]Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 70

I tried to build Vision OS using macOs with Xcode 15.2 for the App I built lacally using 15.3
Here is my code for Azure Inputs
trigger:
- vos-pipeline

pool:
  vmImage: 'macos-13'

steps:
- script: |
    sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode_15.2.app
  displayName: 'Select Xcode 15.2'

- task: Xcode@5
  inputs:
    actions: 'build'
    sdk: 'xros'
    configuration: 'Release'
    xcWorkspacePath: '**/*.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace'
    xcodeVersion: 'default' # Options: 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, default, specifyPath

And the result is the following

/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk xros -configuration Release -workspace /Users/runner/work/1/s/GridControl.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace -scheme GridControl build CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=NO | /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin/xcpretty -r junit --no-color
2024-04-02 11:07:01.119 xcodebuild[1384:8170] Writing error result bundle to /var/folders/0x/nsz8g_tn7cn5l93m_zpy54xr0000gn/T/ResultBundle_2024-02-04_11-07-0001.xcresult
xcodebuild: error: Found no destinations for the scheme 'GridControl' and action build.
##[error]Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 70


Hi, the MacOS 14 is now available for Azure Pipelines. Can you try to use the macos-14 agent and see if it works?


I tried to build Vision OS using macOS with Xcode 15.2 for the App. I built locally using 15.3.

After checking the software list of macos-13 agent, the Xcode 15.2 is with the visionOS 1.0. While you build locally using 15.3 (with the visionOS 1.1), they are not matched in the macos-13 agent.

The Xcode 15.3 is in the software list of macos-14 agent.

I also found a similar error issue, and it is also solved with updating the simulator version with Xcode.
Update:
According to the list, the MacOS 14 is now available for Azure Pipelines.
- job: 
  pool:
    vmImage: 'macOS-14'

